# Embed different website's page into a html/jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, embed

I am trying to develop a web application that will use google search engine.
I am able to embed the page(google.co.in) in my jsp using iframe tag. But what I require that I want to embed only google's search box, not the entire page(image/logo etc.). Is it possible somehow?

Looking for ideas.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question.

Comment: I am stuck at iframe. I am trying to avoid any API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search your website use google custom [search](https://cse.google.com/cse/tools/create_onthefly).